# Reactjs Integration Testing Cognito Native Crypto Module Could Not Be Used To Get Secure Random Number

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js

I have an integration test that uses the AWS Cognito library; specifically, I'm calling CognitoUser.authenticateUser(). When I start my webpage this all works fine: however, in my tests I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Native crypto module could not be used to get secure random number.


at cryptoSecureRandomInt (/source/project/master/website/node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/lib/utils/cryptoSecureRandomInt.web.js:38:9)
at WordArray.random (/source/project/master/website/node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/lib/utils/WordArray.js:50:56)
at randomBytes (/source/project/master/website/node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/lib/AuthenticationHelper.js:47:58)
at AuthenticationHelper.generateRandomSmallA (/source/project/master/website/node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/lib/AuthenticationHelper.js:113:21)
at new AuthenticationHelper (/source/project/master/website/node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/lib/AuthenticationHelper.js:67:29)
at CognitoUser.authenticateUserDefaultAuth (/source/project/master/website/node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/lib/CognitoUser.js:264:32)
at CognitoUser.authenticateUser (/source/project/master/website/node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/lib/CognitoUser.js:237:19)
```

Researching for answers I came across many posts suggesting:

```
 Object.defineProperty(global.self, 'crypto', {
        value: {
            getRandomValues: arr => crypto.randomBytes(arr.length),
        }
    });
```

Unfortunatley that does not work.

Looking at the crypto source:

```
 function cryptoSecureRandomInt() {
    if (crypto) {
        // Use getRandomValues method (Browser)
        if (typeof crypto.getRandomValues === 'function') {
            try {
                return crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0];
            } catch (err) {}
    } // Use randomBytes method (NodeJS)


    if (typeof crypto.randomBytes === 'function') {
        try {
            return crypto.randomBytes(4).readInt32LE();
        } catch (err) {}
        }
    }

    throw new Error('Native crypto module could not be used to get secure random number.');
  }
```

I can see where this error is being thrown. I'm guessing that under normal circumstances the crypto package is loaded by the browser which obviously doesn't exist when testing.

Any suggestions?

**Update 1**

Stepped through using the debugger and in the crypto source it's getting undefined for the 'crypto' variable on this line

```
 if (crypto) {
```

This means that the Object.defineProperty is not working. I tried attaching it to the window but that doesn't work either

```
 Object.defineProperty(window, 'crypto', {
        value: {
            getRandomValues: (arr) => crypto.randomBytes(arr.length)
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm getting the same issue